# Fetch key value from json data using terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

I have a json data file from which I need to fetch only the id attribute value into a separate list variable. I tried for loop but not able to get the required data using terraform. Can someone tell how to fetch the id part ? your help is much appreacited.

code:

```
    locals {
    data = jsondecode(file("./data.json"))[*]
    sections = [ for item in local.data : item ]
}

output "ids" {
    value = [for a in local.sections[0]: a]
}
```

json file:

```
{
"c":[
   {
      "id":"6",
      "key":"c",
      "name":"s01"
   }
],
"l":{
   "id":"7",
   "key":"l",
   "name":"s02"
},
"m":{
   "id":"8",
   "key":"mp",
   "name":"s03"
},
"n":{
   "id":"5",
   "key":"cn",
   "name":"s04"
},
"od":"odk",
"s":{
   "id":"9",
   "key":"cs",
   "name":"s05"
},
"ss":{
   "id":"1",
   "key":"ss",
   "name":"s06"
},
"in":{
   "id":"65",
   "key":"cn",
   "name":"s07"
},
"b":{
   "id":"2",
   "key":"cb",
   "name":"s08"
}
```

}

Comment: What's wrong with your current code? Any errors?

Comment: @marcin, No error, it just output full json data but am trying to fetch only id attribute value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if `"od":"odk",` is mistake or not, but you can do the following:

```
locals {
    data = jsondecode(file("./data.json"))
}

output "ids" {
    value = [for v in values(local.data): v.id if can(v.id)]
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Marcin. learned new stuff in terraform. Many Thanks

Comment: @vrledu No problem. Glad the answer was useful.

Comment: Applogise, I just noticed that from the solution you have provided is going to miss the first items/attribute id ie, id =6 since its list of dict. how can we get all the items id including first one ?

Comment: not sure if you had a chance to see my above message. any idea how can we get all ids

Comment: @vrledu I the moment I don't know. It would be easier to redsign your json to have consistent format.